# Efficient way to solve one sided limits

Tags: calculus, limits

What is a good way to solve this limit problem as $x\to \frac 74+$ of the function $\frac {2x^2-3x-9}{16x^2 -49}$?

How would you solve this problem. Would you have to plug in values close to $\frac 74$ in order to solve this or is there another way?

Comment: Did you mean $$\lim_{x\to\frac{7}{4}^+}\frac{2x^2-3x-9}{16x^2-29}?$$

Comment: @user5139637 Do you know how to factor?

Comment: Simply put the value $x=\frac74$ in the function, if the denominator $\neq 0$, then nothing difficult.

Comment: Ya but does this factor out neatly? If it does then I meant to give an example which doesn't factor out from the top and bottom. What would you do if something on the top and bottom doesn't factor out?

Comment: @MarioG no. I meant the 49

Comment: @SubhadeepDey but in this case the denominator does equal 0

Comment: @user5139637,why? putting the value, the denominator is $49-29=20$

Comment: @user5139637, I think you posted the questionn wrongly, it will be $49$ instead of $29$ in the denominator. I edited this. View the post.

Comment: No i meant (16^2 - 49) in the denominator. sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29017/discussion-between-subhadeep-dey-and-user5139637).

Comment: If top and bottom don't have any factors in common then they can never be both zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set
$x = 7/4+y$
and let $y \to 0$.

$ \frac{2x^2-3x-9}{16x^2 -49}
$

For the denominator,

$\begin{array}\\
16(y+7/4)^2 -49
&=16(y^2+7y/2+49/16) -49\\
&=16y^2+56y\\
\end{array}
$

Note that the constant term
has cancelled out,
so we have to see what happens
in the numerator.

For the numerator

$\begin{array}\\
2(y+7/4)^2-3(y+7/4)-9
&=2(y^2+7y/2+49/16)-3(y+7/4)-9\\
&=2y^2+y(7-3)+49/8-21/4-9\\
&=2y^2+4y+(49-42-72)/8\\
&=2y^2+4y-65/8\\
\end{array}
$

Since the numerator
is not zero as $y \to 0$
and the denominator is,
the limit is
$-\infty$
since the numerator
goes to a negative value.

Comment: The OP has been edited, See this and then post your answer.

Comment: That's annoying.

Comment: I edited this far ago, but @user5139637 loaded this just now. I can do nothing with this.

Comment: I adjusted my answer.

Comment: That's nice solution.

Comment: Thanks. See how the denominator behaves first, and adjust the "precision" of the numerator to match.

Comment: See what the largest power of y that divides the denominator. If the denominator has a constant yerm, that is $y^0$. In the problem here, that is $y^1 = y$. Then the numerator only has to be evaluated to terms of that power of $y$.

Answer (score 0):

You could write $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\frac{7}{4}^{+}}\frac{2x^2-3x-9}{16x^2-49}=\lim_{x\to\frac{7}{4}^{+}}\frac{(2x+3)(x-3)}{(4x+7)(4x-7)}.$

Since $(4x+7)(4x-7)\to0$ and $(2x+3)(x-3)\not\to0$ as $x\to\frac{7}{4}^{+}$, the limit does not exist;

and since the factors have signs $\displaystyle\frac{(+)(-)}{(+)(+)}$ as $x\to\frac{7}{4}^{+},\;\;$ the limit is $-\infty$.